# Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined when using Webpack and vue loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I get this error

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:219 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

When I add this code to my webpack config

```
{
          test: /\.vue$/,
          loader: ‘vue-loader’,
        },
```

Then I get the above error. If I remove the code then I don’t get the error. From researching online It seems that you cannot use vue-cli and vue-loader at the same time. I am using vue-cli. For some more information I am also using Vue 2 and webpack v4.

The reason I want the above configuration in my webpack is because It reduces my build size in half. However when I start up my app with `yarn build` I get the error message in the title.

The app works If I remove that code from my webpack config.

My init.ts is the file that gets ran and starts the app and it looks like this

```
export default function (elementID = 'app') {
  new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(App,),
    store,
  }).$mount(`#${app}`)
}
```

So the render function is definitely there, and everything works just when I remove that webpack code.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: You have a typo in the `$mount` function: `#$app}` should be `#${app}`.

Comment: @Kapcash I fixed the typo and It still doesnt work

Comment: vue-cli uses vue-loader under the hood, so I'm not sure why you're trying to add it manually. If your bundle size is reduced, maybe it's because it doesn't load your code properly, not because it's more efficient.

Comment: @Kapcash thats what I was thinking too, just surprised theres not more posts about this issue